# Is it possible to mute MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my iPhone application I want to mute & unmute MPMoviePlayerController.
I have searched a lot but I am unable to succeed. Is it possible to mute audio in MPMoviePlayer controller?
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:0];
```

This Line will mute the sound(hopefully)..:)

Comment: I have tried by using this API but it wont work because it is for MPMusicPlayercontroller & I want to mute MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: WELL, MPMusicPlayercontroller, MPMoviePlayerController are diffrent? or it just a mistake (of spelling or something).

Comment: +1 for correct answer - @Jyotsna: you just create an instance of the `MPMusicPlayerController` addionally to your `MPMoviePlayerController` and adjust the volume. That `MPMusicPlayerController` instance is almost inactive apart from being used for adjusting the volume.

Comment: @rptwsthi: MPMoviePlayerController do not support applicationMusicPlayer method.

Comment: @Till: Means it's not possible to mute the audio for MPMoviePlayerController?

Comment: setVolume is deprecated in iOS7++. It has also the disadvantage that a "sound turned off" icon is shown for a second. The answer in <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948661/how-to-mute-unmute-audio-when-playing-video-using-mpmovieplayercontroller> says that it is not possible to turn off the sound of a MPMoviePlayerController.

Comment: should be -1 on votes. This is not a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this to mute.

```
NSError *error;
if ( ![[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:&error] ) {
    NSLog(@"Error encountered: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

You will have to include the AVFoundation framework.

Comment: Hi deepak thanks for your instant reply but it also not worked for me, I am checking it on simulator.

Comment: +1 for correct answer - this works just like the solution supplied by rptwsthi. You might need to adjust the player settings on the usage of the audio session to get this to work properly: `useApplicationAudioSession`

Comment: @Till: I also tried to create by using instance still not working.

Comment: Thanks!!! I will also check this on iPad or on iPhone. May be I am working on simulator because of that it's not reflecting any changes.