# How to mute MPMoviePlayerController sound in iPhone

Tags: iphone, session, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller, mute

I have two kinds of media,

- video with sound
- recorded voice audio

I want to play recorded voice audio with video but mute video sound.

To play these medias, I used the MPMoviePlayerController for video and the AQPlayer for recorded audio.

Is it possible?
If so, Anyone has an idea, Please?

Comment: Hello Daniel. If you have found a solution to this. Please share with us.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to mute MPMoviePlayerController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108407/is-it-possible-to-mute-mpmovieplayercontroller)