# How to mute & unmute video player in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I have problem into mute and sound , I have Played the video in iPad using URL then using button I need to mute the audio of that video player.Please help me out dis Problem Thanks.

Comment: Try this... for mute and unmute

[mute/Umnute][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16103329/1673099

Comment: @user1673099 its not work for me it will show some error please help me out,and also if i use that while play onwards it will play mute mode i think.

Comment: Can you post your error?

Comment: @user1673099 dis my code NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www……."];
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
    moviePlayer =[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: fileURL];
      moviePlayer.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 760, 750);
    moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
       moviePlayer.repeatMode=YES;
     moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    [self.view addSubview: moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer play];

Comment: @user1673099 I have used above code to play the video player now i need to use uibutton to mute the video. error i am getting is _kCMTimeZero", referenced from:
      -[GameAppViewController playMovie] in GameAppViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)