# Disable Audio (and interruption) with MPMoviePlayerController using Swift

Tags: swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer, avplayerlayer

At the moment, this is how I'm playing a video on the subview of my UIViewController:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)  {
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("musicvideo", ofType: "mp4")
    self.moviePlayerController.contentURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath)
    self.moviePlayerController.play()
    self.moviePlayerController.repeatMode = .One
    self.moviePlayerController.view.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.moviePlayerController.scalingMode = .AspectFill
    self.moviePlayerController.controlStyle = .None
    self.moviePlayerController.allowsAirPlay = false
    self.view.addSubview(self.moviePlayerController.view)
}
```

I've read on ways to disable the audio by doing the following below (none of which work, at all). Keep in mind I'm trying to disable it to the point of not interrupting the current music playing via the Music app, Spotify, etc.

```
// Playing media items with the applicationMusicPlayer will restore the user's Music state after the application quits.

// The current volume of playing music, in the range of 0.0 to 1.0.
// This property is deprecated -- use MPVolumeView for volume control instead.
```

1) `MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer().volume = 0`

2) `MPVolumeView` doesn't even have a setting for *setting* the actual volume? It's a control.

3) `self.moviePlayerController.useApplicationAudioSession = false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948661/how-to-mute-unmute-audio-when-playing-video-using-mpmovieplayercontroller).

This is my Swift code that I ended up going with. I then used an `AVPlayerLayer` to add to the view as a sublayer, which works perfectly.

Thanks to the OP who managed to get a hold of an Apple technician and provided the original [Objective-C code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948661/how-to-mute-unmute-audio-when-playing-video-using-mpmovieplayercontroller).

The only problems I'm facing now is that it:

**1)** Interrupts current music playback, whether it's from Music, Spotify, etc.

**2)** Video stops playing if I close the app and open it up again.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)  {
    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("musicvideo", ofType: "mp4")

    var asset: AVURLAsset?
    asset = AVURLAsset.URLAssetWithURL(NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePath), options: nil)
    var audioTracks = NSArray()
    audioTracks = asset!.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)

    // Mute all the audio tracks
    let allAudioParams = NSMutableArray()
    for track: AnyObject in audioTracks {
        // AVAssetTrack
        let audioInputParams = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters()
        audioInputParams.setVolume(0.0, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
        audioInputParams.trackID = track.trackID
        allAudioParams.addObject(audioInputParams)
    }

    let audioZeroMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
    audioZeroMix.inputParameters = allAudioParams

    // Create a player item
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    playerItem.audioMix = audioZeroMix

    // Create a new Player, and set the player to use the player item
    // with the muted audio mix
    let player = AVPlayer.playerWithPlayerItem(playerItem) as AVPlayer

    player.play()

    let layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .None

    layer.frame = self.view.bounds
    layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```

Comment: hi @gotnull (nice name!) any chance you could help on this question about capturing video? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704032/swift-video-records-at-one-size-but-renders-at-wrong-size