# How to mute audio using MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, iphone

```
MPMoviePlayerController * _moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
_moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp4"]];
_moviePlayerController.contentURL = url;
_moviePlayerController.fullscreen=NO;

_moviePlayerController.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
for(UIView *aSubView in _moviePlayerController.view.subviews) {
    aSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
// Rotating the player to landscape position
_moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                               0.0f,
                                               [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,
                                               [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);

// _moviePlayerController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
_moviePlayerController.view.center = self.view.center;

UIView *playerView = _moviePlayerController.view;
playerView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f,
                              0.0f,
                              [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width,
                              [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height);


[videoPlayerView addSubview:playerView];
_moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay=NO;
[_moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
[_moviePlayerController pause];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mute/unmute audio when playing video using MPMoviePlayerController?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948661/how-to-mute-unmute-audio-when-playing-video-using-mpmovieplayercontroller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to mute your audio player by using MPMoviePlayerController. If you want to mute your audio player you should add AVFoundation framework. Try this code

```
AVURLAsset * asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[self localMovieURL] options:nil];
NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

// Mute all the audio tracks
NSMutableArray * allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
        AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
        [audioInputParams setVolume:0.0 atTime:kCMTimeZero ];
        [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
        [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}
AVMutableAudioMix * audioZeroMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

// Create a player item
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
[playerItem setAudioMix:audioZeroMix]; // Mute the player item

// Create a new Player, and set the player to use the player item
// with the muted audio mix
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

self.mPlayer = player;

[mPlayer play];
```

Comment: self. mPlayer means MPMoviePlayerViewController

Comment: in your scenario self.mPlayer means _moviePlayerController